# How to pull apk from Work Profile in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, adb, intune

I've run the command adb

```
adb shell pm path com.some.someapplication --user 10
```

but it returns in no result.

Comment: What does `adb shell pm list users` output? Please edit your question and add it there not here in comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, UserID in your case isn't 10. I had the same problem. This is how you can solve :  
Run

```
adb shell pm list users
```

You will get an output in the format

```
UserInfo{0:Owner:c13} running
UserInfo{999:XSpace:801010} running
```

Then use the number in the second user curly braces as the user_id, here it's 999

```
adb shell pm list packages --user user_id
```

Once you know the package name, you can use

```
 adb shell pm path com.some.someapplication --user user_id
```

to pull apk using the package name. 
Example: For linkedin installed in work profile , I use

```
adb shell pm path com.linkedin.android --user 999
```